# Clear previous canvas working with RecyclerView on Android

Tags: android, canvas, drawing, android-custom-view

I am drawing custom ovals using `canvas` in `Android` as follows. In fact, each shape is a view and created with the help of `RecyclerView`. When I click any shape, I draw another oval with **stroke** attribute(white one).

What I want to do here is to remove previous border oval whenever I touch another shape and draw a border for it. Do you have any idea? Thanks.

> Code for drawing a shape:

```
override fun drawOval(canvas: Canvas) {
    canvas.drawOval(shapeRectF, shapePaint)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a list of models. In each model, you need to have filed `isSelected: Boolean`. When you need to draw stroke you set `isSelected = true` to the item you need and `isSelected = false` to the item you want to remove the previous border. Then set new data to the adapter.

In you ViewHolder draw stroke if `isSelected == true`